# Deep learning forecasting MIMO

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I have a dataset with 20 features in a time series. The dimension of the dataset is 45000 x 20 (45000 timesteps and 20 features). Basically, 45000 rows and 20 columns

The data looks like this:
The problem is how to train the first few steps and predict the next few steps in order to get the output of 20 feature predictions which is (A, B, C...). I successfully train and predict 1-D (1 feature (A) for ex) array. But I have no idea how to predict the 20 features using same the dataset.[image: 20 Features (columns representing RPM), each has a 45K power consumption value]

I tried doing it using [LSTM timeseries prediction with multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930518/lstm-timeseries-prediction-with-multiple-outputs) this link with the same code and changed the feature from 3 to 20.

But I am getting below error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15020/722712485.py in 
> ----> 1 history= model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.33, epochs=20, batch_size=16)
> 2
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in
> error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
> 69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
> ---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 71         finally:
> 72             del filtered_tb
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
> tf__train_function(iterator)
> 13                 try:
> 14                     do_return = True
> ---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self),
> ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
> 16                 except:
> 17                     do_return = False
>
> ValueError: in user code:
>
> ```
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
> ```
>
> line 1249, in train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 1233, in step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 1222, in run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 1024, in train_step
> loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 1082, in compute_loss
> return self.compiled_loss(
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py",
> line 265, in **call**
> loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line
> 152, in **call**
> losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line
> 284, in call  **
> return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\yashum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line
> 1500, in mean_squared_error
> return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
>
> ```
> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 20 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} =
> ```
>
> SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_5/dense_5/BiasAdd,
> IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,3], [?,20].

Please tell me how to proceed.